# What are the difference between MS-dos FAT32 format and windows FAT32 format

Tags: windows, dos, fat32

What are the difference between MS-dos FAT32 format and windows FAT32 format?

Comment: What exactly is "MS-DOS FAT32"? According to Wikipedia, "FAT32 was introduced with Windows 95 OSR2".

Comment: FAT32 is a file system.  MS-DOS and Windows are operating systems.  You can run Linux on FAT32 too, and it'll still be the same FAT32.

Comment: MS-DOS support FAT32 by formating harddisk using 'fdisk' and then 'format'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none.. There's only FAT32, no Windows or MS-DOS flavors of it.

Comment: Have you count the LFN extension?

Comment: No, since it's OS' responsibility not FS'

Comment: Technically, VFAT is a trick/abuse of FAT that allows DOS to simply ignore the LFNs; it is not actually a different file-system. Also, while it originally devised in Windows 95, it is certainly available for DOS via a TSR. So it is indeed dependent on how the OS handles the regular FAT32 file-system as opposed to being a variant.

Answer (score 5):

Hum... Fyi, on a mac (running macos), in the Terminal application, you can scan a USB key using the "diskutil" command line utility.
When the key is brand new, you get this result:

`$ diskutil list disk2
/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *16.1 GB    disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 EVERIO_SD               16.1 GB    disk2s1`

If you format the USB key with the "Disk Utility.app", using the "MS-DOS (FAT32)" parameter, then you will get:

`$ diskutil list disk2
/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *16.1 GB    disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 EVERIO_SD               16.1 GB    disk2s1`

So, at least from the point of view of macos, there seems to be a potential difference between "Windows_FAT_32" and "DOS_FAT_32"...

Comment: DOS_FAT_32 is type 0x0B in an MBR partition map.
Windows_FAT_32 is type 0x0C in an MBR partition map.
0x0C is FAT32 with logical block addressing.

Answer (score 1):

FAT32 is a filesystem and has nothing much to do with the operating system. So whatever OS it is, FAT32 is FAT32, and they're the same.

Afaik, MS-DOS used FAT16 as its default filesystem, while FAT32 was first introduced by Win95 OSR2, or Win97 as known by others. I'm FAT32 is not supported by MS-DOS versions before v7.x, which was shipped with Win95 OSR2.

So if your question was "What's the difference between MS-DOS FAT and Windows FAT", the answer would be MS-DOS uses FAT16 while Windows uses FAT32.

Comment: MS-DOS6.22 support FAT32 by formating it using 'fdisk', and then 'format'.